# Is it possible to pass a python object from a config file?

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, configuration, yaml

I don't mind if it's YAML, JSON, .ini, or whatever.

The user should be able to change the `reduction` value in the call to the [tf.keras.losses.CategoricalHinge](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalHinge) function via a configuration file like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# config file reading happens here (expected scenario):
f = read_the_config_file()
reduction = f["reduction"]  # retrieved the reduction value

# pass `reduction` to the loss function:
loss = tf.keras.losses(reduction)
```

`reduction` could either be `tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE` or `tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO`. These values are tensorflow objects.

An example JSON file I'd expect will be like:

```
{
"reduction ": tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE
}
```

But obviously, this is an invalid JSON file.

**Question:**

Are there ways to let user pass this kind of a parameter in a config file?
If not, what are the other ways of getting a such user input without keeping a string to object mapping in the user code?

Answer (score 1):

Look into using [gin-config](https://github.com/google/gin-config), a lightweight config framework that allows you to work with objects in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with Python, but I assume you can implement the `read_the_config_file()` function not only (1) reads the configuration file's contents into a dictionary, but also replaces some string values with object values for a few special entries in the dictionary, such as `reduction` in your example. At least that way, the string-to-object mapping code is encapsulated within `read_the_contents_file()` rather than being spread out in the rest of user code.